# Computationally indistinguishably vs Perfect Indistinguishably

Tags: provable-security, perfect-secrecy, distinguisher

I know that perfect security means absolutely no information about the plaintext is leaked to the adversary while computational secrecy is okay with a tiny amount of leak.

But, what is the difference between Computationally indistinguishably and Perfect Indistinguishably?